# Apply extra CSS property AFTER previous transition is completed

Tags: css, sass, css-transitions

**I have a sidebar that get's the class `.closed` when a button is clicked.**

The animation to set width to zero is working perfectly. The problem is, I have a border on the left side of the sidebar, and when width is set to zero, it appears double thick because it meets with the border on the other side. So after the transition sets `width: 0`, I need to set `border: none` also.

This is what I have, in SCSS. *(If you don't know, `&.closed` is the same as `#sidebar.closed`.)*

```
#sidebar {
  border-left: solid $border-width $border-color;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  width: $sidebar-width;
  transition: width $sidebar-animation;
  transition: border $sidebar-animation $sidebar-animation;
  // Here I tried to set the delay for border.

  &.closed {
    width: 0;
    border: none;
  }
}
```

That's not working. So how do I do it?

Comment: Is this the same menu you were working with in your previous question? If so, setting `border: none` seems to work https://jsfiddle.net/25bnqpoe/2/

Comment: @MichaelCoker It is, but I don't want the border to disappear until _after_ the width reaches zero. It just bothers me that the `<hr>` elements are left with "loose ends" as the sidebar closes.

Comment: how about this? https://jsfiddle.net/25bnqpoe/4/

Comment: @MichaelCokker How the f** does that even work? I _really_ don't understand how CSS works sometimes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Santiago pointed out, you can't transition the shorthand 'border' property. But you can transition border-width and border-color.

You could try to transition the border to the same color as the background instead of none. You could also transition the width of the border to 0.

I tweaked your example a little for a quick and dirty way to make it work with a toggle for demo purposes.

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $('#sidebar').toggleClass("closed");
});
```

```css
#sidebar {
  border-left-style: solid;
  border-left-color: black;
  border-left-width: 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  width: 300px;
  transition: all .25s;
  /* added for demo */
  background: purple;
}

#sidebar.closed {
  width: 0px;
  border-left-color: white;
  border-left-width: 0;
  border-left-style: solid;
  transition: all .25s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sidebar">
<p>Sidebar</p>
</div>

<button>Close sidebar</button>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for a complete answer. I wasn't saying that @SantiagoRebella's answer wasn't correct, it was just incomplete.

Comment: no it wasnt, that is completely nonsense, just look at the first sentence of this answer

Answer (score 1):

I think border is not a valid transition property

https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#transition-shorthand-property[image]

---

the answer from the image would be transition border-left-width to 0

Comment: Ok, so do you have a solution? Because this isn't actually an answer.

Comment: by the way I just put a link to the transition specification and a screenshot of the table of valid border props to transition, and you replied with "Because this isn't actually an answer", let me say, pfff...